# have a batch file call an AS400 macro

Tags: batch-file, macros

I am trying to decrease user intervention when doing an upgrade. I have a batch file that does the ftp portion and restores on the AS400 as follows:

```
@echo off

if EXIST ftpcmd2.dat goto :justRunIt

SET /P userpw= Please enter in QSECOFR password:
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400:


 >ftpcmd.dat echo.open %IPaddr%
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.user
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.QSECOFR
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.%userpw%
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.bin
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.lcd c:\ahc
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.cd /qsys.lib/ahcpgm.lib
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.put PCDIST.savf
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd CLRLIB LANSASHIP
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd RSTLIB SAVLIB(LANSASHIP) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/PCDIST)
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd DLTOBJ OBJ(QGPL/LANSAISHP2) OBJTYPE(*FILE)
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd CRTDUPOBJ OBJ(LANSAISHP2) FROMLIB(LANSASHIP) OBJTYPE(*FILE) TOLIB(QGPL) DATA(*YES)
>>ftpcmd.dat echo.quote rcmd ENDSBS SBS(RELPGMLIB) OPTION (*IMMED)


ftpcmd.dat echo.quit


:justRunIt
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd2.dat
```

When this completes I want to call the AS400 macro to finish the update as follows :

```
Description =
"ahc
[tab field]
"ahc
[enter]
[enter]
"addlible relpgmlib                     
[enter]
"lansa partition(rel) developer(a)
[enter]
"5
[enter]
"8
[enter]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[down]
[up]
"lansaishp2
[tab field]
[down]
[down]
[down]
"yes
[enter]
[down]
[tab field]
"wrksbmjob
[enter]
[pf5]
```

Comment: is there a reason to write `ftpcmd.dat` but execute `ftpcmd2.dat`? `ftpcmd.dat echo.quit` is missing `>>` - typo here only or also in your code?

Comment: Sorry about that. I modified from another that didn't need access to the AS400 and failed to change the FTPCMD to FTPCMD2.